# Problem with wikit, a command line tool to search wikipedia on linux

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 18.04, npm

Hello a couple of weeks ago I installed wikit, a program for displaying summaries of Wikipedia articles on the linux terminal.

The command that I used for the installation was:

```
$ sudo npm install wikit -g
```

The answer shown in the terminal was:

```
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
/usr/local/bin/wikit -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/wikit/index.js
\+ wikit@3.0.0"
updated 1 package in 11.638s
```

I assumed that the program had been installed, but when making a query the result was the following:

```
$ wikit Linux

/usr/local/bin/wikit: línea 2: use strict: orden no encontrada
/usr/local/bin/wikit: línea 4: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `('
/usr/local/bin/wikit: línea 4: `const path = require('path'),'
```

I have installed on my PC kubuntu 18.04.

Thank you.

wikit github page

https://github.com/KorySchneider/wikit

and

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wikit

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Your question doesn't appear to be directly related to Ubuntu.  The command `npm install .... -g` fetches and installs an application from the npmjs system which isn't *technically* Ubuntu software.  Have you tried lodging an issue at https://github.com/KorySchneider/wikit/issues ?  There appears to be an issue raised there already about an hour before you asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is going to seem confusing, but `wikit` isn't actually Ubuntu software.  To install it you had to run `npm install wikit -g` which downloads and installs software from **npmjs**.  That's not to say there aren't npmjs softwares in Ubuntu, but Ubuntu-supported npm softwares are installable via `apt` or `snap`. (The same problem occurs with other out-of-tree respositories like perl's `CPAN`)

As such, Ubuntu doesn't have control over how it's packaged, so in your particular case, it appears that a couple of npm modules in the `package.json` file are out-of-date.

I'd recommend reporting this issue to https://github.com/KorySchneider/wikit/issues as it won't only be happening on Ubuntu.

The interim solution would be to download the application source, and change the "module" reference in `package.json` to the correct versions and then `npm install` from source.